# Boot doesn't display Windows XP and Ubuntu to select the OS

Tags: 12.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 as dual boot to my Windows XP. There was a booting problem: `NTLDR is missing`.

I resolved by adding two system files by copying two files by using Windows XP bootable CD. Now, I am not able to get `Select OS screen` as before. Directly Windows XP is being started. So, I re-installed Ubuntu but still cannot get the OS selection menu.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: include the output of `sudo fdisk -l` on your question

Comment: run `update-grub` from ubuntu and try agian. while running the command it displays operating systems in the system.you can also check `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which is read to display the OS Selection screen

Answer (score 0):

Run sudo update-grub. Sometimes it happens that during installation, the bootloader doesn't detect windows. If it still doesn't show windows. Then just to check that everything is alright, check the file grub.cfg in the folder in the root directory ./boot/grub/ . If it displays the words that go something like "Windows * (loader)" then everything is alright with the grub.cfg file. If this happens, comment.